# How can i run only the unit tests not the integration tests on build phase with maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I added the `maven-failsafe-plugin` to my project for runnig integration tests. When i run `test` only unit tests are running and when i run `integration-test` first unit tests and then integration tests are running.

It's all what i want so far but when i clean and build the project both unit tests and integration tests are running which i wouldn't prefer because i just don't want to prepare the environment for integration testing on every build.
I clean and build the project for some generated source to regenerate and i don't want to run the integration test meanwhile.

Is there a way that i only run the integration tests on purpose not by any automation?

Comment: Usually you should run your unit tests and your integration tests within the build. The question is what needs to be prepared for running your integration tests. I recommend to make the preparation part of your integration tests. Furthermore if you like to run them only on purpose than you should use a profile to make them triggerable. like `mvn clean verify -Prun-its` and using ´mvn clean verify` will not run integration tests. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `-DskipITs` flag `clean install` command of maven so integration tests are not running when i make a call of clean and install.

And i created maven goals as `integration-test` and `verify` to run and verify the integration tests via the `failsafe plugin` which i added to my `pom.xml`.

As i'm using `netbeans` as ide, i set the predefined maven commands via the actions tab of the project properties and i can run the integraion tests via right click to peoject and integration test sub menu under maven menu.

Comment: failsafe recognizes the integration tests with the ```...IT``` acronym at the end of the file name.